# How to insert list of same properties but different values to a relation in ascending order in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have 2 nodes , person and job. The relation between them is VIEWED. I want to store the all timestamps whenever person viewed the job in the list in ascending order and append this list to my relation.

Comment: Could you please describe the data model in a little more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Cypher query uses the [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) clause to create the `VIEWED` relationship if it does not already exist. The `ON CREATE` clause would initialize the `timestamps` list if the `MERGE` clause had to create the relationship, whereas the `ON MATCH` clause would append to the `timestamps` list if the relationship already existed.

```
MATCH (p:Person {id: 123}), (j:Job {id: 987})
MERGE (p)-[v:VIEWED]->(j)
ON CREATE SET v.timestamps = [datetime()]
ON MATCH  SET v.timestamps = v.timestamps + datetime()
```